# Inserting "missing" multiindex rows into a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a pandas DataFrame with a two-level multiindex. The second level is numeric and supposed to be sorted and sequential for each unique value of the first-level index, but has gaps. How do I insert the "missing" rows? Sample input:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(list(range(5)),
                  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('A',1), ('A',3),
                                                   ('B',2), ('B',3), ('B',6)]),
                  columns='value')
#     value
#A 1      0
#  3      1
#B 2      2
#  3      3
#  6      4
```

Expected output:

```
#     value
#A 1      0
#  2    NaN
#  3      1
#B 2      2
#  3      3
#  4    NaN
#  5    NaN
#  6      4
```

I suspect I could have used `resample`, but I am having trouble converting the numbers to anything date-like.

Comment: Create the index by for loop , then reindex it ?

Comment: @Wen-Ben Thanks! That would be my last-resort option. I hate using loops in pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much deliberations, I was able to come up with a solution myself. Judging by the fact of how lousy it is, the problem I am facing is not a very typical one.

```
new_index = d.index.to_frame()\
                .groupby(0)[1]\
                .apply(lambda x:
                         pd.Series(1, index=range(x.min(), x.max() + 1))).index
d.reindex(new_index)
```

Answer (score 2):

If there is a will, there is a way.  I am not proud of this but, I think it works.

Try:

```
def f(x):
    levels = x.index.remove_unused_levels().levels
    x = x.reindex(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([levels[0], np.arange(levels[1][0], levels[1][-1]+1)]))
    return x

df.groupby(level=0, as_index=False, group_keys=False).apply(f)
```

Output:

```
     value
A 1    0.0
  2    NaN
  3    1.0
B 2    2.0
  3    3.0
  4    NaN
  5    NaN
  6    4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the following depends on the missing index:

```
result.unstack(1).stack(0, dropna=False).fillna(0)
```

When you unstack, the pandas expand the df to have rows and columns and in the above example, level 1 index is going to be the column names. Then, again by stacking, you return the df to its original form, BUT, this time you need to make sure you use `dropna=False` so the NaN values are going to be there for missing indexes. In the end, using `.fillna(0)` is optional depends on what you want to do with the NaN values.

Comment: This will also create `(B, 1)` which is not in the desired dataframe. It also doesn't insert the _new_ values `(B, 4)` and `(B, 5)`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no accounting for taste, but I think falling back to list comprehension leads to slightly more readable code:

```py
df.reindex(
    pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
        (level_0, level_1)
        for level_0 in df.reset_index(0).level_0.unique()
        for level_1 in range(
            df.reset_index(1).loc[level_0, "level_1"].min(),
            df.reset_index(1).loc[level_0, "level_1"].max()+1
        )
]))

# Output:
#value
#A  1   0.0
#   2   NaN
#   3   1.0
#B  2   2.0
#   3   3.0
#   4   NaN
#   5   NaN
#   6   4.0
```

Although this is of course slower than going down the `apply` route:

```
list-comprehension: 2.57 ms ± 19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
DYZ apply: 1.25 ms ± 8.75 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
Scott's apply: 2.19 ms ± 9.84 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Little late for the party i see, but for future travelers, I think I found a solution:

Use pandas multiindex from product function to generate all combinations of levels of indices:

```
df_new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([
  df.index.get_level_values(0).unique(),
  df.index.get_level_values(1).unique()])

df_reindexed = df.reindex(df_new_index)
```